# Moving user directory after re-joining the domain with the least amount of pain on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, user-profiles, windows-domain

Unlike Windows XP, it's pretty easy to change a user's sub-directories in Windows 7 like Music and Documents. Go to their properties' location tab and move it elsewhere.

I am looking for similar solution to moving the user's entire directory. Which resides here:

```
C:\Users\Username
```

There was a hiccup in the domain controller (dc), so I had to unplug my machine from the dc and plug it back in. Now I have a new user folder. It's located here:

```
C:\Users\Username.DOMAIN
```

I want to rename `C:\Users\Username.DOMAIN` to `C:\Users\Username`. However, I understand the files under `C:\Users\Username` do not belong to me (anymore), therefore, I'll have to take ownership of them first. Which I did. Then I tried the following registry change:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-UNIQUE-PROFILE-ID
```

Modified the **ProfileImagePath**'s data to `C:\Users\Username`. Then I kept my fingers crossed. Of course, it didn't work.

After restarting the machine and attempting to login using domain credentials failed. It tried to log me in, then it logged me out. So, I had to revert my registry changes. Googling didn't help much. Any ideas on what I can try without screwing it up horribly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming them is a bad idea.  There are just too many unknowns to get your profile back that way.

One of the best tools to look at User State Migration Tool from Microsoft Technet.  It isn't an easy tool to use though.

Comment: You're right. There are just too many unknowns. I was about to do some work around and the result wasn't what I was expecting. For now, I will just copy over the data that I need and start over.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you shouldn't be renaming things...

I would suggest using the [User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html) instead.